# Error in finding the maximum square of 1s inside a matrix

Tags: python, algorithm, matrix, data-structures, dynamic-programming

I am trying to solve a problem wherein I have to find the maximum square of 1s inside a matrix, containing only zeroes and ones.

Full statement is here: https://leetcode.com/problems/maximal-square/description/

My solution is:

```
 def maximalSquare(matrix):
        """
        :type matrix: List[List[str]]
        :rtype: int
        """

        if len(matrix)==0:
            return 0

        maxlen = 0

        dp = [[0 for x in range(len(matrix[0])+1)] for x in range(len(matrix)+1)]

        for i in range(1, len(matrix)+1):
            for j in range(1, len(matrix[0])+1):
                if matrix[i-1][j-1]==1:
                    dp[i][j] = min(dp[i-1][j], dp[i-1][j-1], dp[i][j-1]) + 1
                    maxlen = max(dp[i][j], maxlen)

        return maxlen
```

Sample Run:

```
Your input
[["1","0","1","0","0"],["1","0","1","1","1"],["1","1","1","1","1"],["1","0","0","1","0"]]
Your answer
0
Expected answer
4
```

Now, my logic is simple: if three ones are there arranged in an L shape, the fourth one indicates that a square is present.

But the answer is off by a lot, what is the error I can't really find.

Comment: I haven't run your sample or tried this coding challenge, but your inputs are all strings. Have you tried casting them to int?

Comment: @krflol even putting 1 in quotes in the if condition gives wrong answer

Comment: You can't do math on a string like that. Cast it to int, don't try to run it as a string

Comment: Maybe your expected result really is the proper one, but I find that after fixing the 1/"1" issue, I get results that correspond to the side of the square of ones, so 2 means four ones, and 3 means 9 ones, etc.

Comment: Try simpler test cases, by the way, such as 2x2 ones, and 3x3 ones.

Comment: @ArndtJonasson yes, that is the issue..plz put it ias the asnswer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the matrix contains strings, the comparison should be

```
matrix[i-1][j-1]=="1"
```

rather than

```
matrix[i-1][j-1]==1
```